# List of deprecated CSS properties

Tags: css, deprecated

Is there a list of CSS properties that are deprecated? My friend is telling me that `min-height` is deprecated and I want to be sure that I'm not using any other deprecated property. Also, I want to check if it is true.

Comment: Min-height is not deprecated as far as I can tell. It still appears in the CSS2 specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ and that is the most recent W3C recommendation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the `min-height` property is not deprecated and can be used as normal. For an excellent list of CSS properties and their compatibility with various browsers, try [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

According to the site I linked to above, the `min-height` property is fully supported by every major browser except Internet Explorer 6 (in which it is only supported when applied to `td` elements).

Answer (score 3):

If by *deprecated* he actually means that it isn't supported by **older** browsers instead of **newer**, then yes.

There are a lot of different CSS attributes which are only available for newer browsers as they are part of CSS3. But unlike **html**, css doesn't really have any *deprecated* attributes, unless you take into account css expressions and other IE crap that should have never been there to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

min-height is not deprecated. Try Google...

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that min-height was deprecated. It's fully supported by every browser since IE6...

Comment: Although it's not fully supported by IE6 - only when applied to `td` elements.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might have meant that, but I thought I'd clarify it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

BEST place to look is the [RFCs](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=w3%20html%20rfc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). And then you need to see for each browsers what he decides to support or not (w3schools has a nice list, although not sure it is 100% complete)
[This search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=css%20browsers%20support&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) also brings some results.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a "no-obsolete" rule for [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@isnotdefined/stylelint-plugin) stylelint plugin, there was the need to gather all deprecated CSS at-rules, properties and values.

**At-Rules:**

```
@apply
@document
@viewport
```

**Properties:**

```
box-align
box-direction
box-flex
box-flex-group
box-lines
box-ordinal-group
box-orient
box-pack
clip
grid-column-gap
grid-gap
grid-row-gap
ime-mode
page-break-after
page-break-before
scroll-snap-coordinate
scroll-snap-destination
scroll-snap-points-x
scroll-snap-points-y
scroll-snap-type-x
scroll-snap-type-y
user-modify
```

**Property Values:**

```
box-sizing: padding-box;
image-orientation: flip;
image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
text-decoration: blink;
text-decoration-line: blink;
word-break: break-word;
```